# How to create text file using Groovy?

Tags: file, groovy

I am trying to create a new text file using the below lines of Groovy code in Soap UI but I do not see the file is created

```
import java.io.File 
def newFile = new File("C:/Users/ramus/Documents/Jars/test.txt")
```

Could you please help me in understanding on what is wrong with the above lines of code?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: Your code is doing ...well nothing. It points to some file (existing or not) and that's it

Comment: import java.io.File 
File newFile = new File("C://Users//ramus//Documents//Jars//test.txt") I changed the code like above and it is still not creating the text file

Comment: The code creates File object in memory, which is something,not 'nothing'.  That File object needs to realised on the storage medium, using like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile() or perhaps https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**new File(path)** means create pointer to file or directory with selected path.
Using this pointer you can do anything what you want create, read, append etc.
If you wish to only create file on drive you can do:

```
def newFile = new File("C:/Users/ramus/Documents/Jars/test.txt")
newFile.createNewFile()
```

Answer (score 19):

Just an addition to the accepted answer--if you want to create a file with content, you can do this:

`new File("C:/Users/ramus/Documents/Jars/test.txt").text = "Test text file content"`

This particular feature is one of my favorite parts of groovy, you can even append to a file with +=

Answer (score 12):

Initialise your file:

```
def yourFile = new File("yourFilePath.txt")
```

Delete any record of already existing file. This works even if there is no existing file.

```
yourFile.delete()
```

And finally, Create new file.

```
yourFile.createNewFile()
```

To add content to your file, you can use:

```
yourFile.text="Text content"
```

At this step your file contains : "Text content"

```
yourFile.append=" appended to my file"
```

At this step your file contains : "Text content appended to my file"

```
yourFile.text="New content of your file"
```

At this step your file contains : "New content of your file"

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
def newFile = new File("new.txt")
newFile.write("text to be added to the new file")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to always make sure it's a new file, i.e. overwrite any existing file, you can use:

```
//...Create file... 

file.newWriter.withWriter { it << "some text" }
```